# I have bitlocker keys saved to a text file. Is there a powershell script I can run on a domain controller to save the keys in AD computer objects?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, bitlocker

I have a text file (csv) with bitlocker keys for all my computers. I would like to run a powershell script on a domain controller (and NOT on the computers themselves) to store those keys in Active Directory computer objects of those computers, so that when I open the properties of each computer I can see those keys in "Bitlocker Recovery" tabs.

Also, is there a powershell script I can use to read the information already present in that tab to save it to a CSV? I found a few scripts dating back a couple of years ago but none of them seem to work on my Windows 2019 domain controllers.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

I found a number of articles detailing how to use Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector and similar commandlets to backup the keys to AD but they all seem to need to run from the user computers. I need to be able to import the keys while logged on to the domain controller, from a text file, without bothering end users.